# Replacing $ with Foundation.util.S

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

Is there a way I can make jQuery's $ be powered by [Foundation.util.S](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript-utilities.html#selector)

I'd like to be able to drop in a code snippet into existing code written with $ as the selector and have it powered by Foundation.util.S (which is superior to $ if you are already using Foundation).

Comment: You mean doing `$ = Foundation.util.S`?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: $ = Foundation.util.S gives me an error